# Code for line graph using swing, containing x,y points and plotting them

Tags: java, swing, graph, line

I want a line graph code in which I can change the x,y coordinate value and using the points, I want to plot a line graph. Please help me.

```
public class PaintExample
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        JFrame  f;
        f=new PaintExampleFrame();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }


}
class PaintExampleFrame extends JFrame
{

PaintExampleFrame()
{
    System.out.println("Yay");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("Paint Attempts");
    setSize(300,200);
    setLocation(new Point(500,500));
    setVisible(true);
    setBackground(Color.black);

}

public void paint(Graphics g)
        {
            g.setColor(Color.red);
            g.drawLine(0,0,200,200);
            g.setColor(Color.blue);
            g.drawLine(200,200,70,133);
            g.setColor(Color.orange);
            g.drawLine(70,133,400,15);
    }


}
```

The above code is not working for me. Please post some new code a/c to my requirement.

Comment: "_Please post some new code a/c to my requirement._" We are here to help you solve specific programming problems, not write your code for you. Explain what exactly isn't working and what you have tried so far to solve it. Consider reading --> [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) && [What Can I Ask About](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) from the help section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [Custom Painting Approaches](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/).

It shows how to draw a "colored Rectangle" from an object in an ArrayList. You should be able to modify the code to draw a "colored Line" from an object in an ArrayList.

Comment: hi ji, i dont need rectangle graph, i want to plot a line graph for some given value... thnks for ur response..

Comment: @user3545550, I know you don't need a rectangle graph. I suggested the concept was the same. You store a List of Lines that you want to paint.